# Change to wantsSoftwareDimming in iOS 6?

Tags: ios, ios6

This is regarding the question: [Turn off display in iPhone OS (iOS)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950194/turn-off-display-in-iphone-os-ios)

As alternative to turning off display, I am looking for a way to dim screen as much as possible.

I found following questions:

[How to change brightness in iOS 5 app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207305/how-to-change-brightness-in-ios-5-app)

[Make the iPhone Screen Dim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234981/make-the-iphone-screen-dim)

And this documentation:

http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScreen_Class/Reference/UIScreen.html

Per this questions/documentation, I should be able to do this to dim screen additional to decreasing backlight.

```
 [[UIScreen mainScreen] setWantsSoftwareDimming:YES];
```

I tried this code on my iPad 2 (iOS 6.0). However, I didn't notice any change in brightness of display.

a) Am I doing something wrong?

b) Were there any changes in iOS regarding this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`setWantsSoftwareDimming:` won't on itself do anything to the screen. It will instead change the scale that the `brightness` property of `UIScreen` uses. You should be calling it *before* you call `setBrightness:`. Perhaps if you post the method in which you set the brightness / call `setWantsSoftwareDimming` you might get some more useful feedback?