# Swift, prevent device lock but allow turn off lcd light (dim screen)

Tags: swift, ios8

I am building application using swift 2 targeting minimal iOS 8.

I need to present my application all the time without interrupted by device lock.

I am aware and currently using `UIApplication.sharedApplication().idleTimerDisabled = true` to disable device locking.

The question is, is it possible (and how ?) to prevent device lock, but allow the screen to be dimmed (light off) ?

The goal is to save a bit more battery by turning off lcd light (without turning it off or lock device).

Thank you.

Comment: Possibly related?  [Keep display on when the proximity sensor is covered](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27147847/2415822)

Answer (score 10):

You cannot prevent the dimming, but you can set the brightness during the app operation. You will still disable the idle timer, but modify the brightness manually.

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().idleTimerDisabled = true
UIScreen.mainScreen().brightness = CGFloat(0.1)
```

Few notes regarding your question:

- Brightness values are between 0.0 to 1.0
- If the the app did enter to background (idle timer is enabled), the brightness value will go back to the user settings
- [Settings a Display's Brightness](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIScreen_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006903-CH3-SW18)

**Swift 3**

```
 UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true
```

Answer (score 7):

For my case we do not want the device to auto lock or dim. We have the snippet of code

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().idleTimerDisabled = true
```

In Swift 4+

```
UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true
```

In the view controllers that should not auto-lock or dim, yet our devices are still dimming but not auto-locking. For us this is annoying and a bug but for you it sounds like it's what you want. Although from other posts I have found:

1. [iPhone - phone goes to sleep even if idleTimerDisabled is YES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1679814/iphone-phone-goes-to-sleep-even-if-idletimerdisabled-is-yes/29256860#29256860)
2. [idleTimerDisabled not working since iPhone 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058717/idletimerdisabled-not-working-since-iphone-3-0)

It seems to be device specific, let me know if this helps.

Comment: Yes, what you've described is what I want. But the code you provided doesn't help. Thanks anyway.