# .plist alternative for setIdleTimer

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7

i'm looking for something similar to setIdleTimer but as a .plist value.
I just want to keep my app active even if the user is not using it for a while.
Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you want a way to set a custom value for the idle timer?

Comment: I mean i want to set a value (which i dont know yet) within the .plist to let the screen stay not black.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know the only way to keep your app active is by setting

```
@property(nonatomic,getter=isIdleTimerDisabled)       BOOL idleTimerDisabled;     // default is NO
```

for `UIApplication`, that is

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];
```

If you want to set a different time you can do an hack by keeping the app active, running your own timer and [dimming the screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8234981/make-the-iphone-screen-dim) when needed, but I am not sure it is worth the effort.